# PHP Mysql with fetch array

Tags: php

```
$bagianWhere = "";
if (isset($_POST['chkBadge']))
{
    $badge_id = $_POST['badge_id'];
    if (empty($bagianWhere))
    {
        $bagianWhere .= "t_emp.badge_id = t_balance.badge_id".
                        "and E.badge_id = '$badge_id'";
    }
}

$query = "SELECT t_emp.badge_id, t_emp.emp_name,
                 t_balance.badge_id, t_balance.balance_amount
          FROM   t_emp, t_balance 
          WHERE  ".$bagianWhere ;

$hasil = mysql_query($query);

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
```

I don't know what happened with my PHP code. I tried hard, but still facing problem with error like this :

`Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...`

Anyone advice please.

Comment: echo your query and check

Comment: fyi: mysql_fetch_array() is deprecated, try to use mysqli_fetch_array()

Comment: This is basic debugging 101. Echo your query, check your error logs, use an `or die()` when calling `mysql_query()`. **Do some work yourself**

Comment: make sure your query is correct or not? you just echoing your query and check it out.

Comment: And what if `$_POST['chkBadge']` or `$badge_id` does not exists ?

Comment: your query is wrong, there is no table for E as you mentioned in your where block. echo your query and execute that query directly in ur phpmyadmin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m not test but replace your query

```
$query = "SELECT t_emp.badge_id, t_emp.emp_name,
                                    t_balance.badge_id, t_balance.balance_amount
                                    from t_emp, t_balance WHERE 
                        '".$bagianWhere."'" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make change as below :

```
1)  $bagianWhere .= " where t_emp.badge_id = t_balance.badge_id and E.badge_id = '$badge_id'";


2)  $query = "SELECT t_emp.badge_id, t_emp.emp_name,
                                        t_balance.badge_id, t_balance.balance_amount
                                        from t_emp, t_balance  
                            ".$bagianWhere ;
```

In your case if condition is false Query become something like this :

```
SELECT t_emp.badge_id, t_emp.emp_name, t_balance.badge_id, t_balance.balance_amount where  from t_emp, t_balance
```

Try as below :

```
$bagianWhere = "";
        if (isset($_POST['chkBadge']))
        {
            $badge_id = $_POST['badge_id'];
            if (empty($bagianWhere))
            {
                $bagianWhere .= " where t_emp.badge_id = t_balance.badge_id and E.badge_id = '$badge_id'";
            }
        }

        $query = "SELECT t_emp.badge_id, t_emp.emp_name,
                                    t_balance.badge_id, t_balance.balance_amount
                                    from t_emp, t_balance  
                        ".$bagianWhere ;

                        $hasil = mysql_query($query);
                        while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning an error so mysql_query returns FALSE. This causes mysql_fetch_array to fail.

Most likely `$badge_id` is empty (you do check if chkBadge is set, but not if badge_id is set). Echo your query and run it through MySQL manually to verify its correctness.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no matching records in the results or there may be some error in your query when the values are substituted. So that it is returning Boolean false which is a Boolean. So try to execute your query in MySQL directly.